# Issue when import java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I got a problem when i try to import an java project to Eclipse.

The Eclipse don' build my packages, he construct a directory structure like

```
com
   Test
       Test2
            Test3
                 -- and then my .java files
```

How can I do to import this project with my package ?

Comment: `import com.Test.Test2.Test3.<class>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a source folder to your project.